# UIImageView not showing up

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiimageview, xcode6

I have a UIImageView with property, it's connected in the storyboard and in viewDidLoad I have set it's image. I first create an image then assign it to the image of the UIImageView.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]resizeableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(28.5, 5, 6.5, 5)];
    [self.imageView setImage:image];
 }
```

I've made sure numerous times that the UIImageView is connected in the IB and it's showing up as connected. I have a UICollectionView over it, but it doesn't extend high enough to cover it all and the UICollectionView background color is set to clear. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Most likely is that `imageNamed` failed and returned nil. Set a breakpoint on the last line and check `image` and `self.imageView` for nil.

Comment: Anything in particular I need to be looking for? I'm not too saavy on reading that output. Even setting a background color, I get nothing.

Comment: If you hover the mouse over the word `image`, the debugger should display a popup with more information about the `image` variable. Likewise, for `self.imageView` hover over the word `imageView`. All you care about is whether it says `nil`.

Comment: That makes no sense.  It should say something like `(_UIResizeableImage *) 0x9815b00` If it says `(UIImage *) 0x1` then the type is wrong, and the pointer is invalid, neither of which can happen with the code that you've posted.

Comment: There are two other ways to look at your variables. One is to use NSLog. For example, `NSLog(@"%p",image);` displays the pointer value of `image` in hex, or `NSLog(@"%@",image);` would print a description of `image` assuming that `image` points to a valid object. The other method is to examine variables in the "Debug area". The "Debug area" should automatically display at the bottom of the Xcode window when you run the code in the debugger. By default, the left pane of the "Debug area" shows your variables, and the right pane shows the console.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you added the `IBOutlet UIImageView * imageView` in your .h and then linked it in the Interface Builder, BUT did you add the property of the imageView? Like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView * imageView;
```

And then in your .m file, under the `@implementation` you need to add `@synthesize imageView;`
and set the image to your imageView using only: `[imageView setImage:image];` (without the self.).

(You can also skip the @synthesize and just use `[_imageView setImage:image];`)

The @property allows you to edit the properties of the object, like backgroundColor, alpha, image, etc.

Comment: Had the properties, it was checked to be invis on the IB. Such small things sometimes can stop a train. Thanks for the help you all.